# MediaCodec createInputSurface

Tags: android, surfaceview, h.264, android-mediacodec

I want to use MediaCodec to encode a Surface into H.264.

With API 18, there is a way to encode content from a surface by calling createInputSurface() and then drawing on that surface.

I get IllegalStateException on createInputSurface(). Here's additional logcat output:

```
D/H264Encoder(17570): MediaFormat: {frame-rate=25, bitrate=1000000, height=600, mime=video/avc, color-format=19, i-frame-interval=75, width=800}
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  125): NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 4 
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  125): NvRmPowerModuleClockControl on MOD[29] INST[0]
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  125): NvRmModuleResetWithHold deassert MOD[29] INST[0]
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(  125): NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 4 
I/ACodec  (17570): setupVideoEncoder succeeded
E/OMXNodeInstance(  125): OMX_EnableAndroidNativeBuffers failed with error -2147479547 (0x80001005)
E/OMXNodeInstance(  125): createInputSurface requires AndroidOpaque color format
E/ACodec  (17570): [OMX.Nvidia.h264.encoder] onCreateInputSurface returning error -38
W/MediaCodec(17570): createInputSurface failed, err=-38
```

Any insight on how the new API works would be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The important error message is this:

```
createInputSurface requires AndroidOpaque color format
```

For Surface input, you *must* set the color format to `COLOR_FormatSurface` (also known as AndroidOpaque.)

See examples [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/), notably EncodeAndMuxTest.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! I assumed that it has something to do with this but couldn't find anything on AndroidOpaque