# MediaCodec.createInputSurface() throws IllegalStateException on some devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, video-processing, android-mediacodec

I'm working on a video processing app. The app has one `Activity` that contains a `Fragment`. The `Fragment` in turn contains a `VideoSurfaceView` derived from `GLSurfaceView` for me to show the preview of the video with effect (using OpenGL) to users. After previewing, users can start processing the video.

To process the video, I mainly apply the method described in [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java).

Everything works fine on most devices, but the [Oppo Mirror 3](http://www.gsmarena.com/oppo_mirror_3-7193.php) (Android 4.4). On this device, everytime I try to create an `Surface` using `MediaCodec.createInputSurface()`, it throws out `java.lang.IllegalStateException` with code `-38`.

```
E/OMXMaster: A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
E/SoftAVCEncoder: internalSetParameter: StoreMetadataInBuffersParams.nPortIndex not zero!
E/OMXNodeInstance: OMX_SetParameter() failed for StoreMetaDataInBuffers: 0x80001001
E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.encoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err -2147483648
E/OMXNodeInstance: createInputSurface requires COLOR_FormatSurface (AndroidOpaque) color format
E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.encoder] onCreateInputSurface returning error -38
E/VideoProcessing: java.lang.IllegalStateException
                at android.media.MediaCodec.createInputSurface(Native Method)
                at com.ltpquang.android.core.processing.codec.VideoEncoder.<init>(VideoEncoder.java:46)
                at com.ltpquang.android.core.VideoProcessing.setupVideo(VideoProcessing.java:200)
                at com.ltpquang.android.core.VideoProcessing.<init>(VideoProcessing.java:167)
                at com.ltpquang.android.ui.activity.PreviewEditActivity.lambda$btNext$12(PreviewEditActivity.java:723)
                at com.ltpquang.android.ui.activity.PreviewEditActivity.access$lambda$12(PreviewEditActivity.java)
                at com.ltpquang.android.ui.activity.PreviewEditActivity$$Lambda$13.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Playing around a little bit, I observed that:

- BEFORE creating and adding the `VideoSurfaceView` to the layout, I can create `MediaCodec` encoder and obtain the input surface successfully. And I can create as many as I want if I release the previous `MediaCodec` before creating a new one, otherwise I can only obtain one and only one input surface regardless how many `MediaCodec` I have.
- AFTER creating and adding the `VideoSurfaceView` to the layout, there is no chance that I can get the input surface from the `MediaCodec`, it thows `java.lang.IllegalStateException` always.
- I've tried removing the `VideoSurfaceView` from the layout, set it to `null`, before creating the surface, but no luck for me.

I also tried with suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052567/mediacodec-createinputsurface-throws-illegalstateexception-in-android-emulator), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845859/mediacodec-createinputsurface), but they didn't help.
From [this](https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/2), it seems that my device can only get the software codec. So that I cant create the input surface.

My question is:

1. Why was that?
2. If the device's resources is limited, what can I do (release something for example) to continue the process?
3. If it is related to the software codec, what should I do? How can I detect and release the resource?
4. Is this related to GL contexts? If yes, what should I do? Should I manage the contexts my self?